# Extracting positive and negative numbers from char array

Tags: java

I am trying to extract both positive and negative numbers from a character array (which is coming from a file). Apparently the method I wrote only worked for positive numbers. Can anyone please tell me how to modify this to handle negative numbers as well?
So let's say my character array is

`{'1',' ','2','-','2',' ','3','4'}`

it should output a list containing

`{1,2,-2,34}`.

Some guidance will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

My method is:

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> extractIntegers(char[] characters) 
{
    int beginning = -1;
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++)
            {
                boolean isNumber = Character.isDigit(characters[i]);
                    if (beginning != -1 && !isNumber) {
                        numbers.add(parseIntegers(characters, beginning, i));
                        beginning = -1;
                    } else if (beginning == -1 && isNumber) {
                        beginning = i;
                    }
            }
                    if (beginning != -1) {
                        numbers.add(parseIntegers(characters, beginning, characters.length));
                    }
    return numbers;
  }

/*Parses characters to Integers*/
private static int parseIntegers(char[] characters, int begin, int end) {
    return Integer.parseInt(new String(characters, begin, end - begin));
  }
```

Comment: while there is more char { read char. If char is a number: convert it to integer and store it. Else If char is `-`and there is a next char, convert next char to Integer and store it negative value.}

Comment: @jhamon: Thanks! but can you guide me how I can modify my existing code to do that?

Comment: Your problem is unclear as you can't give us an accurate input example. Once you said it's an array of digits and sign, newt it's separated by spaces, and now each part is on a differnt line, separated by `\n`char.

Answer (score 2):

Try your function something like:

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> extractIntegers(char[] characters) {
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    char lastValue = 49;//let it be int 1
    for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        if (characters[i] == ' ') {
            continue;
        }
        boolean isNumber = Character.isDigit(characters[i]);//is really a digit?
        boolean isSign = (lastValue == '-');//is last char value that we read really a '-'
        if (isNumber) {
            if (!isSign)
                numbers.add(((int) characters[i] - 48));
            else
                numbers.add((int) -1 * ((int) characters[i] - 48));//if last token was "-" multiply by -1
        }
        lastValue = characters[i];
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

Comment: your var names are confusing. `isSign` is flase when last value is a sign. And what if `lastValue`is neither a digit or a `-`? You should replace Character.isDigit(lastValue) with `lastvalue == '-'` and invert your condition

Comment: Thanks. This code is returning more output values than the inputs

Comment: I tried for your input and it returns fine. Can you paste what input you tried?

Comment: It is actually all on a new line like this: 
1
-3
1
3

Comment: Sorry, over here, I could not make it print on new line, but all my inputs are on a new like: 1\n-3\n1\n3 etc

Comment: what's that you store in char array? it should be char[] array = { '1', '-', '3', '1', '3' }; So if you haven't sorted out that, you need to sort that first and then apply the method above.

Comment: U r right. But technically, my output list should have 64000 values, and using your method returns 77783. Not sure what extra characters are adding

Comment: it will return you the list with elements [1, -3, 1, 3]. Not sure where 64000 or 77783 comes from for your input  { '1', '-', '3', '1', '3' } Hope you are not post processing with the output form this method and asking why that output.

Comment: what **exactly** is passed as argument to your method? Almas's code can only return less characters than the input. You probably misuse his code.

Comment: I have spaces in my char array.That is what I meant

Comment: if you don't give an accurate exemple, it's hard to help you

Comment: Ok. Here is my input:  char[] a={'1',' ','2','-','2',' ','1','2'}; This should return [1,2,-2,12]. Thanks in advance and sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Shehlina you should be very clear when raising the issue. This i consider as follow up question. Anyways, i have edited the post for you. Please check.

Comment: @almas shaikh he also states `{'1','2'}`should return `[12]`. That's different from the first stated behaviour... Edit: OP said: "all my inputs are on a new like: 1\n-3\n1\n3"... It would be easier to read the input file line by line and convert each line to int.

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace for loop in your code and try with this:

         for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
                boolean isNumber = Character.isDigit(characters[i]);
                if(!isNumber) {
                     if(characters[i]=='-') {
                         i++; // to read next digit
                         if(i<characters.length &&  Character.isDigit(characters[i])) {
                         numbers.add(Integer.parseInt((String.valueOf(characters[i])))*-1);
                     }
                     }                   
                }
                else {
                    numbers.add(Integer.parseInt((String.valueOf(characters[i]))));
                }
            }
```

Comment: if `characters[i]` is the last char in the list, it will throw an exception. Same problem if a `-` follows an other `-`

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain?

Comment: Thanks @jhamon I have modified. It will work input file contain valid number. If contains '-','-','4' then it will not work.

Comment: how would you handle an input like this? {' ','1','2','-','2'} with space that is?

Comment: @Shehlina that has already handled. It will just omit other character without '-', even '+'

Comment: or an input like {' ',' ','1','2','-','2'} This shud return 12,-2 and {'1',' ','2',' ','-','2'} shud return 1,2,-2

Comment: What is your number seperator? if a it is '1','2' it may 12 or 1,2.

Comment: in my char array, number separator is a space, not a comma

Answer (score 0):

```
    private List<Integer> extractIntegers(char[] characters) throws Exception 
    {
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++)
        {
            boolean isNumber = Character.isDigit(characters[i]);
            if (isNumber) {
                numbers.add(Character.getNumericValue(characters[i]));
            } else if (characters[i] == '-' && i+1 < characters.length && Character.isDigit(characters[i+1])) {
                i++;
                numbers.add(Character.getNumericValue(characters[i]) * -1);
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Corrupted char array");
            }
        }
        return numbers;
     }
```

e.g

char[] chars = {'1', '2', '-', '5'};
--> 1 2 -5

char[] chars = {'1', '2', '-'};
--> Exception

char[] chars = {'1', '2', '-', '-', '6'};
--> Exception

char[] chars = {'1', '2', '1', 'a', '6'};
--> Exception

Comment: Thanks. Your method makes sense. But it is throwing exception and reaching the point "Corrupted char array"